# Изменились URL постов WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с таким интересным моментом, обновил сайт на WP до последней версии и заметил что у постов поменялись урлы. Возникает вопрос:

Может ли WP после обновления генерировать новые урлы постам, по текущим тайтлам постов?

Привожу пример:

Был пост

- Title: Одноэтапная имплантация зубов
- URL: http://site-name/odnoetapnaya-implantatsiya-zubov/

Стал пост

- Title: Одноэтапная имплантация
- URL: http://site-name/odnoetapnaya-implantatsiya-zubov/

После обновления WP стал

- Title: Одноэтапная имплантация
- URL: http://site-name/odnoetapnaya-implantatsiya/

Comment: WordPress не трогает слаги (url). Это у вас какие-то плагины шалят.

Comment: ок, буду тестить, спасибо за ответ